# sendmessage not working for jetaudio in vb6

Tags: vb6, sendmessage

i am trying to implement the Jetaudio API in vb6...
i have taken the values of the constants from the API SDK..

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
 ByVal lpClassName As String, _
 ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long


Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage _
Lib "user32" Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" _
(ByVal lpString As String) As Long



Public Const WM_APP As Long = &H8000
Public Const MyMSG As Long = WM_APP + 740


Public Function GetJetAudioSong()
Dim v As Long
Dim JAhwnd As Long


Dim lngMyMsg As Long

lngMyMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(MyMSG)

JAhwnd = FindWindow("COWON Jet-Audio Remocon Class", "Jet-Audio Remote Control")

v = SendMessage(JAhwnd, lngMyMsg, 0, 995)
MsgBox v
End Function
```

Now, FindWindow() is working cause JAhwnd is set with a value...
its just the sendmessage() that doesn't seem to be working...

the code is suppose to msgbox the version number for the running Jet Audio instance.

i've been at it for days now and i have no way of making sure weather this error is a VB thing or not... i am taking Jet Audio's SDK's word that the values of the const are correct...

the value of v is always 0 where it should be 6 on my system.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `RegisterWindowMessage`, MyMSG is message number that you should send to the Jet-Audio window.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
 ByVal lpClassName As String, _
 ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Public Const WM_APP As Long = &H8000
Public Const MyMSG As Long = WM_APP + 740

Public Function GetJetAudioSong()
Dim v As Long
Dim JAhwnd As Long

Dim lngMyMsg As Long

JAhwnd = FindWindow("COWON Jet-Audio Remocon Class", "Jet-Audio Remote Control")

v = SendMessage(JAhwnd, MyMSG, 0, 995)
MsgBox v
End Function
```

Comment: thanks but no it doesnt work... i tried ur code... thats how i was doing it before i read somewhere that in VB6 i must register messages before sending it via SendMessage. well what now then?

Answer (score 0):

What Windows Version?
SendMessage and SendKeys no longer works with VB6 code starting at Windows Vista and above.
Do a Google search for it.

Comment: windows 7 32 bit... its strange u say that... winamp SDK uses sendmessage() and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 years too late. Please use this as a future reference for anyone reading this in the future.

The fix for your issue is this:

```
'[ Use 'ByVal' for your lParam to make sure you are passing the actual value not the Reference
v = SendMessage(JAhwnd, lngMyMsg, 0, ByVal 995)

'[ Or you could perform PostMessage(..) and not use ByVal
v = PostMessage(JAhwnd, lngMyMsg, 0, 995)
```

Also, i HIGHLY recommend against anyone using SendKeys. API is the correct method to ensure you are sending message to the correct hWnd. I would suggest using SendKeys only if in desperation; it can happen.